# Detect pointer events on certain widgets that are inside an IgnorePointer or AbsorbPointer

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to detect, for example, a tap event on a certain Widget that is inside an `IgnorePointer` or `AbsorbPointer` in Flutter?

Code example:

```
AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: *some condition to make it true or false*,
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      SomeButton(
        onTap: () => print("i want this method to run when this button is tapped even if absorbing is true"),
      ),
      ...
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity why are you using a widget just to take the main functionality of that widget away I'm just curious? So the answer for `AbsorbPointer` is yes you can have a widget wrapped in `AbsorbPointer` and `RawGestureDetector` then define your own gesture factory to override `rejectGestures` so it accepts all gestures then the`GestureArena` will still register taps. For `IgnorePointer` this setup will not work. I cannot figure any setup that overrides `IgnorePointer`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
          //Column Content
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

You could also wrap `AbsorbPointer` in `Listener` because this doesn't use the `GestureArena` if you want to read more about this Nash wrote a great article about it [Flutter Deep Dive: Gestures](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-gestures-c16203b3434f)

Comment: Hi @wcyankees424, I know it does look strange why would I want that. Basically, I have a ListView that I don't want the user to be able to scroll it (only when the Widget behind it, that is some sort of drawable, is fully expanded) but I want the user to be able to tap on its children. I can achieve this with physics but changing them while the ListView is scrolling gives me an exception sometimes so I thought about using an AbsorbPointer so that I can reproduce the same effect without having an exception. I'll try this solution and I'll come back to you, thanks!

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working, I mean, it does print the instance.onTap but I want it to execute the onPressed event of the Widget I'm clicking that is inside the AbsorbPointer not the instance.onTap. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay I see the issue if you want to enable individual button clicks then yea this setup wouldn't work. It only detects clicks on the screen as a whole. If I understand your issue though your content is larger than the screen but you want to use ```NeverScrollablePhysics()``` but that is giving you an error. what you want to do is try ```SingleChildScrollView``` I adjusted code above.

Comment: Did you ever check out this answer

Comment: Hi @wcyankees424, I'm very sorry for the late answer. That didn't work as there's a certain point where the ListView needs to become AlwaysScrollablePhysics.